# Derangement or what?

Tags: algorithm

I was looking at the description of a derangement that states "a derangement is a permutation of the elements of a set such that none of the elements appear in their original position".  But then it gave 9 derangements for a set of 4 items.  That doesn't make sense to me, because I only get 4 discrete sets from 4 items.

For example:

1234
3142
2413
4321

Is there a different term than derangement for sets where the numbers don't have the same order as in any other set, based on a particular number of items?

And does anyone know of an algorithm for generating the derangements?

Comment: It's not often that I seek a "Closed: Off Topic:  Migrate to http://mathoverflow.com " but there you have it.

Comment: The definition is that none of the permutations has elements in the same position as the **original** set, not that the positions have to be distinct across all other derangements.

Comment: Its related to an algorithm for finding unique sets of a given number of items, so I just wanted to know if that had a name or if I was already looking at it.  Is my question still off topic?

Comment: Actually I rephrased the question on mathoverflow, and the answer appears to be "latin square".  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Kirk - "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer **research level math questions**" - from their [FAQ](http://mathoverflow.net/faq).

Comment: @ChrisF, ack, yeah, should have been http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

The nine derangements are:

```
2143
2341
2413
3142
3412
3421
4123
4312
4321
```

As you can see, column 1 does not contain `1`, column 2 does not contain `2` and so on. In addition, every row has the numbers `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` and there are no duplicates (they're sorted to make that easier to detect).

---

For what it's worth, that was discovered with a brute force attack (the attack space was relatively small):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int a, b, c, d, skip;

    for (a = 1; a <= 4; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= 4; b++) {
            for (c = 1; c <= 4; c++) {
                for (d = 1; d <= 4; d++) {
                    skip  = (a==1) || (b==2) || (c==3) || (d==4);
                    skip |= (a==b) || (a==c) || (a==d);
                    skip |= (b==c) || (b==d);
                    skip |= (c==d);
                    if (!skip) {
                        printf ("%d%d%d%d\n", a, b, c, d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for illustrating that.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was looking for a complete latin square (row-complete and or column-complete).  I had already coded an algorithm to detect those, but didn't know if this kind of thing had a name.  That's it, thanks.